# Check whether an Eclipse view is visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a plug-in action which shows a view & hides a view. Here is my code:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.showView("com.sample.views.Example");
page.hideView(page.findView("com.sample.views.Example"));
```

But how can I check whether this view is in present foreground or if it is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IWorkbenchPage.findView` will return `null` if the view is not open.

`IWorkbenchPage.getActivePart()` returns the active part (this might be an editor or a view).

You can also use `IWorkbenchPage.addPartListener` to listen for changes to the parts.

Comment: I'd like to amend that `IWorkbenchPage.isPartVisible()` can be used to determine if a part is actually visible whereas `findView()` returns a view if it exists but might as well be hidden by another part in the same part stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
IEditorReference[] editors = page.getEditorReferences();
//  How many editor open..
//  System.out.println("Len : "+editors.length);

if(editors.length==0){
        System.out.println("View is not visible");
}
else{
        System.out.println("View is visible");
        System.out.println("View or Editor Name is :: "+page.getActiveEditor().getTitle());
}
```

---

> Current working view or window name display

```
IPartService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService();
    MessageDialog.openInformation(HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(
            event).getShell(), "Current Workbench Window", service.getActivePart().getTitle()+"");
```